# Webkit build on windows | CMake Error: Could not create named generator Visual

Tags: build, cmake, phantomjs, visual-studio-2017, webkit

I got this problem when i'm trying to build webkit on windows

> CMake Error: Could not create named generator Visual

I'm using Visual Studio 2017, and this is the command

> perl Tools/Scripts/build-webkit --qt --release --only-webkit --no-device-orientation --no-web-audio --no-video --no-video-track --no-touch-events --no-touch-slider --no-geolocation --no-xslt --no-netscape-plugin-api --cmakeargs="-Wno-dev -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="C:\Qt\static\5.7.1-msvc" -G "Visual Studio 15 2017""

I need this to build phantomjs 2.1.1, i followed the step from [this page](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/15018). How to fix this?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOpm6.png)

Comment: As you can see from error message, CMake think that generator name is `Visual`, not `Visual Studio 15 2017` as you pass to it. This is because you use **nested double-quotes** in command line, which never works. However, I don't know how to properly pass CMake option's value with spaces in it. You may try to escape them: `Visual\\ Studio\\ 15\\ 2017` (one level of esaping is consumed by the shell itself).

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thank you! It worked, but I have slightly changed the command =>  **perl Tools/Scripts/build-webkit --qt --release --only-webkit --no-device-orientation --no-web-audio --no-video --no-video-track --no-touch-events --no-touch-slider --no-geolocation --no-xslt --no-netscape-plugin-api --cmakeargs="-Wno-dev -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="C:\Qt\static\5.7.1-msvc"" -G Visual\ Studio\ 15\ 2017**

Comment: As you have been able to resolve the problem, you may add an answer to your question. On Stack Overflow [self-answering is perfectly accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Tsyvarev , 
I just need to escape the spaces in **Visual Studio 15 2017** and put generator arguments outside of the nested double-quotes

> perl Tools/Scripts/build-webkit --qt --release --only-webkit --no-device-orientation --no-web-audio --no-video --no-video-track --no-touch-events --no-touch-slider --no-geolocation --no-xslt --no-netscape-plugin-api --cmakeargs="-Wno-dev -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="C:\Qt\static\5.7.1-msvc"" -G Visual\ Studio\ 15\ 2017